# Problem with connecting to wireless modem windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I am using windows 7. I have wireless modem. I could connect to wireless network and internet until some hours ago. but from that time I can' connect to wireless network. when I try to troubleshooting using windows 7 tool It returns this window for me : 
[image] 


Here is my ip Configurat[image]ion : 

Any suggestions / solutions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it the old "Unplug and plug back in" trick. Sometimes if you are running a router from the modem etc they get confused and need to boot up in the right order (time will fix this for you.)

Make sure you download the latest drivers/firmware. You can then access the the wireless device from any internet browser using the IP address. There will be a ton of settings open to you there, some routers have firewalls that are enabled, etc etc.

Windows 7 troubleshooting never works :(

```
ipconfig /release
```

Followed by

```
ipconfig /renew
```

could lead to fixing it as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the short run, go to Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center>Change Adapter Settings, and right-click on your wireless adapter and disable, then re-enable it.

In the long run, see if there is a driver update for your wireless network card, and a firmware update for your wireless access point/router.

Comment: If that first thing does not do it, you may need to recreate your wireless connection (SSID, encryption type, password, etc.). It is also possible your hardware just failed, but not as likely as the connectiong just got screwed up somehow (nothing you did specifically).

Comment: Thank u for your answer , I tried disable and re-enabling wireless adapter but it not works.

Comment: Then try going into Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center>Manage Wireless networks, and delete the one you are trying to connect to (right-click, "Remove network), and re-adding it (add button is hidden there in plain sight near the top). If neither works, it may be hardware-related.